# Error : from PIL import Image

Tags: import, python-imaging-library

I want to create a wordcloud in Python 2.7 (in OS X Yosemite).

I install the package from but when I execute:

```
from PIL import Image
```

an error appears:

```
from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Did you load the `libjpeg.8.dylib` library?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to  install the [prerequisites](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html#os-x-installation).

> ## OS X Installation
>
> We provide binaries for OS X in the form of Python Wheels. Alternatively you can compile Pillow from soure with XCode.
>
> The easiest way to install external libraries is via Homebrew. After you install Homebrew, run:
>
> `$ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2`
>
> Install Pillow with:
>
> `$ pip install Pillow`

Comment: I did all and I was looking for in internet, without exit. The problem is going  on: ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: image not found